# Getting error while trying to fit model - The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter

I am trying to fit a model using keras but I get the following error -

WARNING:tensorflow:From /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
Epoch 1/100

classifier.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=100,batch_size=10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be many reasons for the Kernel dying, the most common one I encounter is because I have ran out of memory.

If you are training a particularly large model try temporarily reducing it and bringing the batch_size down to 1

(I don't think the warning message is related - this is just giving advance warning of a future change)